# Alternative to the functionality of python packages win32api, win32com for Mac

Tags: python, macos, winapi

I am attempting to run a python candy crush bot on my Mac. Unfortunately, it appears the code as written works for Windows.

Specifically, the code defines the following functions:

```
def win32_click(x, y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0) 

def do_move(move):
    start = move[0]
    end = move[1]

    start_w = get_desktop_coords(start)
    end_w = get_desktop_coords(end)

    win32api.SetCursorPos(start_w)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, start_w[0], start_w[1], 0, 0)
    time.sleep(0.3)
    win32api.SetCursorPos(end_w)
    time.sleep(0.3)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, end_w[0], end_w[1], 0, 0)

    win32api.SetCursorPos((1100, 1100))
```

As the author notes in his commentary (link below), he could not find an easy way to make it run cross-platform.

The code in its full context can be found in the git repo, in `main.py` (link below). My goal is to have this body of code run on my Macbook, with the ultimate goal being to write a similar script to play 2048. Like the original author, I do not need to have it run cross platform, although that would be bonus.

Now, finally, for the question: How can this functionality be implemented in a Mac?

References

Git Repo:   https://github.com/AlexEne/CCrush-Bot

Author commentary:  http://www.clickalot.me/2015/05/candy-crush-bot/#comment-4

Answer (score 1):

```
$ pip install pymouse
```

then later

```
>>> from pymouse import PyMouse
>>> # instantiate an mouse object
... m = PyMouse()
>>> m.click(x,y)
```

see also https://code.google.com/p/pymouse/wiki/Documentation

see also https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput